# Зациклить клик по кнопке через js с условием

Tags: javascript

Необходимо зациклить клик по кнопке через js и если объект пропал на странице то прекратить кликать.

Скажем так, заходим на страницу, видим **кнопку** с классом "**button-red ng-star-inserted**", отлично начинаем кликать с периодичностью **1.5** секунды и продолжаем до тех пор пока этот класс присутсвует на странице. Как только класс "**button-red ng-star-inserted**" пропал останавливаем скрипт.

вот модифицированные код который дали совет я его поставил но он продолжает кликать даже если объекта нет

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  for (var i = buttons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    if(button.getAttribute('class') == 'button-red ng-star-inserted') {
        button.click();
    }
  }  
}, 1500);
```

Comment: Каким образом пропадает класс "button-red ng-star-inserted"? Скрывается, удаляется элемент с этим классом, удаляется атрибут class и т.д.?

Comment: он полностью удаляется с html кода - <button _ngcontent-c152="" class="button-red ng-star-inserted">Показать еще</button>

Comment: Посмотреть бы html "потрогать".. Что по клику вызывается? В скрипте еще не хватает остановки интервала clearInterval(interval).. Html есть возможность добавить?

Comment: у меня изначально был код без интервала, но в таком случае он просто нажимает 1 раз и все.
  
нас странице 60 карточек, и выводятся она по 6шт. но само кол-во карточек может быть всегда разное, по этому и хочу условие продолжать нажимать до тех пор пока не пропадет элемент со странице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если касательно конкрететно автодока, то вот рабочий пример с MutationObserver. Скрипт при появлении кнопки "показать еще" нажимает её.
Можете прям в браузере в консоли проверить.

```
    document.querySelector('.center.ng-star-inserted .button-red.ng-star-inserted').click();
    
    let target = document.querySelector('.product-items');
    ​
    const config = {    
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    };
    
    const clickBtn = function(mutationsList, observer) { 
      for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
        for(let node of mutation.addedNodes) { 
          if (node.className == 'button-red ng-star-inserted' ) node.click();
        }
      }
    }
    
    const observer = new MutationObserver(clickBtn);
    ​
    observer.observe(target, config);
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо)